# How to write into File to avoind OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory

The following function runs into java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, though I increased the memory for my project.
This happens at the line `sb.append(CostMatrix[k][j]);`
I guess that the reason is inefficient writing into the file. Instead of storing all the data in `CostMatrix`, it would be probably better to write the file line by line, each time renewing `sb`. How this can be implemented?

```
private static void saveDistanceMatricesToCSV(int i, List<Object[]> data)
{
    System.out.println("Saving distance matrix " + i + " to CSV");
    try
    {
        String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        File file = new File("clusters/d"+i+".csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int len = data.size();
        double[][] CostMatrix = new double[len][len];
        for (int k=0; k<len; k++)
        {
            for (int j=k; j<len; j++)
            {
                double lat1 = (Float) data.get(k)[3];
                double lon1 = (Float) data.get(k)[4];
                double lat2 = (Float) data.get(j)[3];
                double lon2 = (Float) data.get(j)[4];
                double dist = distfunc(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2);
                CostMatrix[k][j] = dist;
                CostMatrix[j][k] = dist;
            }           
        }

        for (int k=0; k<len; k++) 
        {
            for (int j=0; j<len; j++)
            {
                sb.append(CostMatrix[k][j]);
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(NEW_LINE);
        }
        bw.write(sb.toString());
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) :

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
```

Then, instead of appending to a *StringBuilder*, just print to the output :

```
printWriter.println(NEW_LINE);
```

Comment: Thanks. How then should I handle CostMatrix? Do you mean pw.print(CostMatrix[k][j]); pw.print(",");  ?

Comment: ungarida did answer this, I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

I see various sources of inefficiency. You are doing 2 identical couples of *for* cycles:

- first couple: iterate *data* strucure and populate *CostMatrix* (by the way in java variable names start with lowercase)
- second couple: iterate *CostMatrix* to populate the *StringBuilder*.

As already told you by Berger you can avoid the *StringBuilder*, but I would also remove the second couple of for cycles, removing the in-memory usage of *CostMatrix* and moving the writing istructions directly in the first couples of cycles.

Comment: The only thing that should be additionally done in this case is the usage of for(int j=0;...) instead of for(int j=k;...)

Answer (score 0):

You can write each line to the file as below.

```
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            sb.append(CostMatrix[k][j]).append(",");
        }
        output.write(sb.toString());
        output.newLine();
    }
```

BufferWriter's newLine also uses  system property line.separator.